# CMD change modified date of each file recursively

Tags: command-line

Simply `touch` each file in every folder.

I use the following command (it starts in the current location) but - **the issue is**:

- it copies files from nested folders to the main folder instead of leaving them in their original locations

  `FORFILES /S /C "cmd /c COPY @file /B+ ,,/Y"`

Answer (score 3):

#### It copies files from nested folders to the main folder

> ```
> FORFILES /S /C "cmd /c COPY @file /B+ ,,/Y"
> ```

Replace `@file` with `@path` and add the target filename as follows:

```
FORFILES /S /C "cmd /c COPY /B /Y @path @path"
```

Notes:

- `@file` is the **name** of the file.
- `@path` is the **full path** of the file.
- If you only specify the source address, then the files will be copied into the current directory.

---

#### Further Reading

- [An A-Z Index of the Windows CMD command line](http://ss64.com/nt/)
- [A categorized list of Windows CMD commands](https://ss64.com/nt/commands.html)
- [forfiles](http://ss64.com/nt/forfiles.html) - Select a file (or set of files) and execute a command on each file. Batch processing.

Comment: I feel like it should work but it doesn't. I've created folder `test` with `file1.txt` and a folder inside `nested` with `file2.txt` and I've ended up with both files in the main (parent) `test` folder.

Comment: Try `FORFILES /S /C "cmd /c COPY /B /Y @path @path"`

Comment: Answer updated.